# Create custom Framework using xcode project

Tags: ios, iphone

I have created a login functionality in my project and I want to use the same functionality for my next two projects. The goal is to make one login project and create a framework out of it for future use.

Is it possible to create a custom framework with an Xcode project? Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: There come down to many view controller, it should in one project, so I suggest you do not do that.

Comment: Instead of this any suggestion?